# C# nullable warnings в условии, где уже есть проверка на null

Tags: c#, linq, null

```
if (currentAsm[i].IsClass && currentAsm[i].Namespace != null 
                && currentAsm[i].Namespace.Contains("parse", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Непонятно, почему среда разработки подсвечивает

> currentAsm[i].Namespace

как dereference of a possibly null reference, хотя в этом же условии есть проверка на null

В аналогичном примере с использованием linq, nullable warning отсутствует, когда есть проверка на null

```
.Where(type => type.FullName != null && type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Contains("parse", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

И второй вопрос, как лучше оформлять перенос множественного условия в Where? Так как перехода на новую строку сразу с табуляцией нет, самому таб нажимать или делать, как предлагает VS? Например,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или так (сам табом форматирую):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: " хотя в этом же условии есть проверка на null"  --- проверяешь ты значение в `Namespace` но при этом не учитываешь тот факт, что `currentAsm[i]`  может быть `null`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если добавить условие `currentAsm[i] != null`, варнинг все равно остается, от него можно избавиться  `currentAsm[i].Namespace?.Contains("parse", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true` но непонятно, почему варнинг остается, если все необходимые проверки уже есть. Или, скорее всего, я чего-то не понимаю :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно проверить, что currentAsm[i] is not null.

```
if (currentAsm[i] != null...
```

Если property Namespace не является nullable string - string? - проверка на null бесполезна и выдаст варнинг.

Но, очевидно, что currentAsm содержит Types и поэтому Namespace property - string?.

Когда вы оцениваете nullable property с методом, который возвращает boolean, результат будет nullable boolean.

```
Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'
```

Решение заключается в сравнении результата с non nullable значением: x == true

Таким должен быть и ваш код:

```
if (currentAsm[i] != null
    && currentAsm[i].IsClass
    && true == currentAsm[i].Namespace?.Contains("parse", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Или, лучше - чтение массива только один раз

```
var t = currentAsm[i];
if (t != null
    && t.IsClass
    && true == t.Namespace?.Contains("parse", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Имена важны. currentAsm должен быть currentType.

Также, задавая вопрос, лучше сказать, что в массиве Type.

Comment: `Если property Namespace не является nullable string - string? - проверка на null бесполезна и выдаст варнинг`

А если в классе по ошибке будет убран namespace? программа скомпилируется (я проверял)

Comment: `Таким должен быть и ваш код:
`
У меня в VS в таком случае currentAsm[i]!.Namespace все равно подсвечивается с варнингом. Убирается только если добавить ! после Namespace

Comment: Меня осенило, что в массиве Type и я исправил свой ответ